# Raising minimum iOS Deployment Target Version for App Update

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, deployment, app-store

Let's say we have an application with a deployment target set to 3.0 and we want to raise the deployment target to 3.2.  Normally, the App Store won't let the App be installed on devices with an IOS version less then this, but what about devices which already had the App installed prior to the update?  Will they see the update but won't be able to install, will they just not see the update or, heavens forbid, will be able to install and the app just won't start?

I searched everywhere for this, but I can't find anything about raising the minimum OS version for an app update.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great question! Remember to mark correct answers as such so that folks will be motivated to help you again.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From my experience those updates just won't show up as available.

When I upgraded OS on my device from 3.1 to 4.1 about 10 available updates appeared immediately in App store app - so that should be the actual behavior.

Comment: that's my experience as well when we updated a minimum target from 2.2.1 to 3.0 (so quite a while ago)

Comment: However, there is one problematic case, and that comes from upgrades performed from within iTunes or on a device with a higher version number that is then synced to iTunes.  When the user syncs the older device with iTunes, iTunes will actually delete the application from the device because it cannot run the new version currently within iTunes.  I had a couple of users with original iPod touches report this when I upgraded one of my applications to only support 4.0.

Comment: I have a similar scenario: our app is 3.2 (minimum target), we want to raise to 4.3 (to remove armv6 support), will it be accepted?

Comment: I *think* it will, but there's always a little bit if doubt with apple :)

Comment: Does Apple have any official documentation around this?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon, I have not seen that exact information. e.g. nothing is mentioned in "App distribution guide" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW21)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to only showing supported updates, the store now offers the "last compatible version". This lets people download an app even if their device doesn't support the most recent version. Unfortunately this means that some people could still download an older version with bugs you have already fixed. There may be a way to disable this, but none of my app updates have introduced new requirements, so I can not test.

Comment: Here's Apple official how last compatible version is supposed to work for end user: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201377

Answer (score -1):

It's *nearly* a safe bet that they won't be allowed to install it. A similar situation is iPad apps or Mac apps which won't display in the App Store on iPhones and iPods.

I say nearly because the updates should not appear to older users on their iOS devices. The risk, however, is when users sync with iTunes, or if they update with another device. The new version of the app is now associated  with their account, and will ruin the install on the older device if they try to sync it with iTunes.

Comment: As noted by @BradLarson above - they *can* install it, and it destroys their existing app. They may then find it's impossible to re-install. Apple does not "have this covered", except that "Apple is delighted to force you to bin your working device, and buy a new one, because it's free cash for them". (speaking as a developer frustrated by getting blamed by customers for something Apple does apparently out of simple greed)