# Upgrade an application with higher deployment target on App Store

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, upgrade

I've got an application (not free) on the Appstore, it was one of my first app. I'd like to update it with a lot of new stuff, graphics etc. Most of these new feature such as collection views are available only from iOS 6, the app targets iOSes >=3.1. 
 I prefer to not mess around with runtime checking. 
Since is a paid application I'd like at least that all people with iOS6 could upgrade it for free, and I don't want to screw older versions.
What happens if I submit an upgrade that target only iOS=>6, would older iOSes be notified about the upgrade? could they do the upgrade? will be shown something such as "The upgrade will be available only for iOS>=6"? or it will be notified only with matching devices?
I've read that question (little bit old) and there is a Use Case not clear to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434459/raising-minimum-ios-deployment-target-version-for-app-update)
Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @ChrisConway hi, no I still didn't tried, but searching for info on the internet came out that most probably only newer devices will be notified about the upgrade. A problem can arise when an old user delete the application and request to install again after the upgrade. In this case the system will show a popup saying that the application will not run on that version of iOS.

Comment: That's what I found out, too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434459/raising-minimum-ios-deployment-target-version-for-app-update