# iOS App with 6.1 Deployment Target

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

Submitted an app for review and by accident set the Deployment Target to 6.1, instead of 4.3 (which in the previous version it worked perfectly on). Does this mean that if a user is using iOS 5 (for example) they will not be able to download it? Also, will Apple reject it as I am only using 6.1 (and not later)? Thanks.

Comment: First part of the question is answered here: [Raising minimum IOS Deployment Target Version for App Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434459/raising-minimum-ios-deployment-target-version-for-app-update?rq=1). And of course Apple won't reject your app if you use 6.1 as deployment target. But I would recommend to reject the app and resubmit with your desired deployment target. For the reason to do this see Brad Larsons comment on the linked question.

Comment: Just read the link you sent. Why don't you think they'll reject it? After all, it is an option in Xcode!

Comment: your app only gets rejected if there is an isssue with the binary. development target cant be the reason. as stated by matthias reject the binary and change your developement target and re submit the binary, or wait until it gets approved and then send an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your deployment target is set to 6.1 any iOS user with an earlier iOS version will be unable to install your app.  This will not get your binary rejected by Apple.

You can manually reject the binary and resubmit it with the correct deployment target, which is probably what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for this - really helpful information.