# Updating app for iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8

I have an application whose minimum version has been set to iOS 7.0. This application also uses `NSUserDefaults` dictionary. This application is using `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` extensively (not sure how much Apple non-disclosure covers). Now, with iOS 8.0, these two views have been deprecated and have been replaced by controller `UIAlertController`. Now, there are two ways that I can see which can help me in updating the app for iOS 8.

- Raise the minimum version to iOS 8.0 for the update. This way, the users running iOS 7.0 won't be able to see the update. However, it leads to the following situation :-

> However, there is one problematic case, and that comes from upgrades
>   performed from within iTunes or on a device with a higher version
>   number that is then synced to iTunes. When the user syncs the older
>   device with iTunes, iTunes will actually delete the application from
>   the device because it cannot run the new version currently within
>   iTunes. I had a couple of users with original iPod touches report this
>   when I upgraded one of my applications to only support 4.0.

The above comment is present under the accepted answer at the following url :-

[Raising minimum iOS Deployment Target Version for App Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434459/raising-minimum-ios-deployment-target-version-for-app-update)

Since, the application is using NSUserDefaults dictionary, the relevant entries in the dictionary would get erased when the application is deleted.

- The other option is for me to detect in the code which version is being used and code accordingly using if-else statements. This would enable me to keep the iOS 7.0 as the minimum version and *might* also help me in deploying the update for iOS 8.0. However, this seems like a lot of work which can potentially lead to bugs.

So, I was wondering which option is better between the above 2 ways ? (This application would only be using Objective-C for now due to some constraints).

Comment: The NDA is much looser than it has been in the past. You can talk about the view controllers!! And it would help us to help you to name them.

Comment: Why can't you just use controller "C" everywhere where you were using "A" and "B"?

Comment: I think, more than a technical question, this is your commercial decision. It seems that a higher development cost will give you more users.

Comment: @DylanGattey :- Updated the code to show the names. UIAlertController is not available in iOS 7. So, cannot use it.

Comment: Hmmm - I'm not convinced by your comment about apps being deleted from devices. I have an iPhone 3G running iOS 4; it contains several apps where the developer has moved on to requiring iOS 5 (or later). These updated apps are downloaded by iTunes. When I sync with iTunes it does NOT delete the apps from my device rather it gives me an error message that it can't sync them over. The apps are not deleted from the phone and their data is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do from the user's perspective is probably to code using `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` even though they're deprecated. Keep your iOS 7 target the same as it's been. Xcode shouldn't give you warnings since you're using the older version as your base target. You won't need to change anything about your code and it should still work well enough.

Once you're ready to switch (perhaps when iOS 9 comes out), I would switch your base target to iOS 8 and update your code to use `UIAlertController` everywhere. To me, it doesn't make sense to spend time trying to support two different versions if it's just an API deprecation that still allows your code to work how you've written it for years. Saves resources and energy to just update it later.

But it's really up to you and how much you want to support iOS 7. I think it doesn't make sense to drop support until the next version comes out. I always try to support the current and last versions so there are no annoyed customers, but it depends on your own needs.

If you have analytics integrated, check out percentage of iOS 8 adoption once it's been released for the public. If not, it's a great opportunity to add it to find out how up to date your customers are!

Comment: ok. I tried changing my deployment target to 8.0 in order to find out if I would get any warnings. I did not got any warnings for UIAlertView and UIActionSheet. However, I did got a warning for UISearchDisplayController stating that it has been deprecated. But, my app is working fine in the simulator. So, does this mean that the UISearchDisplayController would work in iOS8 even though it has been deprecated ?

Comment: Probably. Deprecated still means that it works but Apple won't support that API in the future. So use something else when you stop supporting iOS 7. It's always good to not use deprecated frameworks, but in a setting like this when you're supporting different iOS versions, there's no great way around it.